# gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, npm

I am trying to install libxmljs package by using npm install libxmljs

and give that you need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.

Although I have installed VS 2017 and tried all the solution [in this documentation](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows) but all fail.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65258925/how-to-fix-node-js-error-like-gyp-err-find-vs-including-the-desktop-developme Here is the solution of @drunkdolphin.