# How to fix node.js error like "gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload." when I launch Nuxt.js project

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js

I have used Nuxt.js in my latest project and I changed the new PC to development
my project.
So I installed node.js same as I usual procedure.
And then I launched new nuxt.js project used by "create-nuxt-app" in command. but, error message is occurred like below.

```
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
```

I think this error message is depend on the node.js.
So, I followed these error message and I installed "Visual Studio" with C++ using Visual Studio Installer in my Windows PC.
but still same error occurred.

I tried to use "windows-build-tools" command in PowerShell of Admin.
command is like that.

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

but still same error occurred.
and I thought node version might be high, so I need to down node version "14.15.1" to "14.10.1".
but never fix my problem.

I almost gave up, but nuxt.js are installed correctly.
I have to fix it.
I searched many times but I couldn't fix it.
Please anyone advise me? Please......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed [this pages.](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp)
first of all, I made binding.gyp file in "C:\Users\your user name\build" like below.

```
    {
    "targets": [{
        "target_name": "binding",
        "sources": [ "binding.vcxproj" ]
    }]
}
```

my code "sources" is binding to "VS ++C".
In window Command prompt run below command↓

```
$ node-gyp configure
↓
$ node-gyp configure --msvs_version=2019※I already installed vs_version=2019
↓
$ node-gyp build
```

That's it ! It was really simple way to pass c++ with node.js.