# node-gyp error Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

The problem that I am having is that I cant install the packages for a project, it keeps erroring with:

```
npm ERR! npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS valid versions for msvs_version:
npm ERR! npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
```

I have tried to follow advice from these threads that other people had:

[How to fix node.js error like "gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload." when I launch Nuxt.js project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65258925/how-to-fix-node-js-error-like-gyp-err-find-vs-including-the-desktop-developme)

And this [How can I solve error gypgyp ERR!ERR! find VSfind VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57879150/how-can-i-solve-error-gypgyp-errerr-find-vsfind-vs-msvs-version-not-set-from-c)

But neither seemed to help.

What I have done so far:

- I installed the latest VS Code (2022 Community) with `Desktop development with C++` along with `MSVC v143 - VS 2022 C++ x64/x86 build tools`
- I have configured `msvs_version` to have the value of `2022`, I did that with `npm config set msvs_version=2022` and with `node-gyp configure --msvs_version=2022`
- I have tried installing windows build tools `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` but it just says that `...Node.js now incldues build tools for Windows...`
- I have also manually built the node-gyp using the commands found in the second post I listed above `node-gyp configure` `node-gyp configure --msvs_version=2022` `node-gyp build` and its all greens and oks

And I have no idea what else I can do

Comment: I'm running `npm install` and getting this error. I don't have C++ and I don't want it that I know of. My project is nodejs project in vscode. Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the problem after hours of searching, it was my node version, i was at 16.x.x, I installed node version manager and moved to version 14 and it worked.

Comment: Thanks. It works for me too. I think Node.js 16 Windows installer have a bug

Comment: Problem still persists with node 18

Comment: My machine having node version 14.19.0, and still facing the issue.

Comment: Solved it by downgrading nodejs is probably not the best answer.

Answer (score 8):

Solved node-gyp in Windows 11, VSCode, Visual Studio 2022

```
node -v
v18.4.0

nvm version
1.1.9

node-gyp -v
v9.0.0



node-gyp configure --msvs_version=2022
```

[image]

Start Visual Studio Installer

[image]

Beside Visual Studio Community 2022 -> Modify ->Individual Components
Type Visual C++

[image]

Make sure MSVC v143 ... x64/x86 build tools (Latest) is checked.

Check current Windows version

[image]

[image]

Back to Visual Studio install, type SDK, and find the correct SDK version.
for me, Windows 11 SDK (10.0.22000.0)

[image]

After all those setup..
I still get

```
gyp ERR!  find VS - does not match this Visual Studio Command Prompt
```

knowing that I have to hack the code

adding this 3 lines above the error log

```
    +this.addLog("this.envVcInstallDir: " + this.envVcInstallDir)
    +this.addLog("vsPath: " + vsPath)
    +this.addLog("path.relative(this.envVcInstallDir, vsPath): " + path.relative(this.envVcInstallDir, vsPath))
    if (this.envVcInstallDir &&
      path.relative(this.envVcInstallDir, vsPath) !== '') {
      this.addLog('- does not match this Visual Studio Command Prompt')
      return false
    }
```

and tracing into

```
    if (process.env.VCINSTALLDIR) {
      this.envVcInstallDir =
        path.resolve(process.env.VCINSTALLDIR, '..')
      this.addLog('running in VS Command Prompt, installation path is:\n' +
        `"${this.envVcInstallDir}"\n- will only use this version`)
    } else {
      this.addLog('VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt')
    }
```

[image]

Finally, have to add something at the end of VCINSTALLDIR

Problem solved, will uninstall VS 2017 & 2019 to save space.

Comment: This answer is very thorough and it worked for me, substituting Windows 10.

Comment: such a great idea to log-debug gyp! thanks! in my case I needed to change VCINSTALLDIR value

Answer (score 2):

Not sure which one (or combination) of the steps that i took solved the issue, but they were:

1. Updated to latest `node.js` version (`v18.12.1` as of writing this) and ran `chocolatey` ("install additional packages" checkbox) through the installer, it updated `python` to `3.11`.
2. Removed all visual studio build installs, except for `2017`.
3. Ran command `npm config set msvs_version=2017`.
4. Restarted my machine.
5. Ran the `nodejs` repair option of the installer.

And that's it!

For context, I was updating an `Angular` project 14 -> 15 and started running into these issues.

Along the way I've also installed `Visual Studio 2022 Community` with the `Development with c++` workload, but `node-gyp` was still not recognizing it.

Also had `Visual Studio Build Tools 2019` that i've uninstalled.

The `2017` version I'm running is `15.9.43`.

Hope this helps someone in the future :)

Comment: Reran the nodejs installer, ran `npm install` again and no errors. I don't have Visual Studio only vscode, it's a nodejs project. I don't know why I was getting the error when running `npm install`  in my nodejs project but repair seems to work now. The installer mentioned something about installing chocolate (Visual C++) tools during install initially so maybe it failed to install the first time and worked on the repair.

Answer (score 1):

I solved by the below steps:

After installed the `Visual Studio 2019 Community` with the `Development with C++`

I still see the error  `msvs_version does not match this version` on my npm install log

So I run `npm config get msvs_version` to check the current `msvs_version`

Then I set it to match with my install `Visual Studio` version

`npm config set msvs_version 2019 --global`

[Image of Got Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XGVM.jpg)

[Image of Fixed the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYbMq.jpg)